How to avoid repetitive calls to a function with arguments of different types fitting the same generic parameter?
I'm very new to rust, so I concede off the bat that there may be a better third way to do this, but I'm very interested in what someone more experienced with the language has to say.
Given a generic function with signature:
fn process_lines<T: BufRead + Sized>(reader: T, re: Regex) {

What is the more "conventional" rust approach to calling this?
There is the straight forward approach:
match input {
    "-" => {
        let stdin = io::stdin();
        process_lines(stdin.lock(), re)
    }
    _ => {
        let f = File::open(input).unwrap();
        process_lines(BufReader::new(f), re)
    }
};

In other languages I would avoid writing out function calls multiple times by doing something that I think would translate as this:
let reader: Box<dyn BufRead> = match input {
    "-" => {
        let stdin = io::stdin();
        Box::new(stdin.lock())
    }
    _ => {
        let f = File::open(input).unwrap();
        Box::new(BufReader::new(f))
    }
};

process_lines(reader, re);

Is there a better way to construct reader other than calling Box ?
This is a super trivial situation, but I'm worried I am falling into some kind of mental trap doing things the way I'm accustomed to...
I understand there is a some performance penalty for using Box...  but I would imagine this is more of a problem inside some sort of nested control flow.
Which of these patterns scales better in large rust code bases, or it is always a per case kind of call?
Any and all insights on this dichotomy (or false dichotomy if there is indeed a third way) are really appreciated!

Maybe this is really hinting to me that creating the reader itself should be abstracted out so that I just call: process_lines(create_reader(input), re) ?  But I'd probably end up using Box again ...

This is, essentially, a missing feature, sometimes called enum impl Trait in discussions – see for example https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/extending-impl-trait-to-allow-multiple-return-types/7921.

You can at least avoid the Box overhead by using &mut dyn io::BufRead instead. Declare let (mut r0, mut r1); in a scope containing the process_lines call, then have each match arm assign to either r0 or r1 and return a &mut to that variable. Then pass that reference as the argument to process_lines.

Temporary lifetime extension has been landed in rust 1.79, which makes it possible to write this:
let reader: &mut dyn BufRead = match input {
    "-" => &mut std::io::stdin().lock(),
    _ => {
        let file = std::fs::File::open(input).unwrap();
        &mut std::io::BufReader::new(file)
    }
};

process_lines(reader, re);

Temporary values that are generated in if, match, and raw blocks, with borrows that escape the scope of the block, would have extended lifetime to match the borrows' lifetime.
This is useful for many dynamic dispatch cases, which are not supported in the earlier versions.

Note however that this probably incurs a small performance penalty as opposed to calling process_lines twice. On the flip side, the compiled code should be smaller with this solution.

Thanks!  This is quite useful to be aware of.

@Jmb There is an unstable support for devirtualization which may remove this performance penalty in some cases

@Alsein, the unstable feature you linked is for virtual function elimination which is not the same as devirtualization. Devirtualization already occurs for local function calls but even if global devirtualization is implemented one day, I doubt it would apply here since process_line may be called with two distinct concrete types.
